# could not find function "spread"

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, spread

So at the moment I am trying to figure out how to build a movie recommender system from MovieLense (https://grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/100k/). I read some instructions from a tutorial.

```
library(dplyr)
library(recommenderlab)
library(magrittr)

data <- read.table("u.data", header = F, stringsAsFactors = T) 
head(data)

   V1  V2 V3        V4
1 196 242  3 881250949
2 186 302  3 891717742
3  22 377  1 878887116
4 244  51  2 880606923
5 166 346  1 886397596
6 298 474  4 884182806
```

Explanation: `V1` is userid, `V2` is itemid, `V3` is rating

Now I need to log format to ratingMatrix, and the result will be like this:

```
    1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
1   5  3  4  3  3  5  4  1  5  3
2   4 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  2
3  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
4  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
5   4  3 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
6   4 NA NA NA NA NA  2  4  4 NA
7  NA NA NA  5 NA NA  5  5  5  4
8  NA NA NA NA NA NA  3 NA NA NA
9  NA NA NA NA NA  5  4 NA NA NA
10  4 NA NA  4 NA NA  4 NA  4 NA
```

code:

```
temp = data %>% select(1:3) %>% spread(V2,V3) %>% select(-1)
temp[1:10,1:10]
```

> Error in spread(., V2, V3) : could not find function "spread"

Comment: So, R can't find the function `spread`. Is it the one in `tidyr`?

Comment: @DiscoSuperfly find it in tidyverse

Comment: @Ching `tidyverse` is a collection of packages. One of the package is `tidyr`, and `spread` is from `tidyr`. As a result, load the `tidyr` package is likely to solve your question, too. Type `?spread` and see the documentation and you can see it is from the `tidyr` package. Next time, if R cannot find certain functions, it would be great if you can google the function name to see the origin of this function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try replacing `library(dplyr)` with `library(tidyverse)`.  The `spread` function now lives in the `tidyr` package which is part of the `tidyverse` along with `dplyr`.

Comment: Yeah, it works :)